Developing a poisson equation solver for arbitrary input geometry and boundary conditions
I need to develop a Poisson equation solver that can take a input geometry and boundary conditions, produces a FEM mesh, generates the matrices and solve it. Problem is I want a solver that can use cylindrical coordinates when we are simulating carbon nanotube cylindrical structures as well as the cartesian coordinates. The boundary conditions are Dirichilet at some edges, Neumann at others, the matlab em solver couldn't handle the combination of boundary conditions that i wanted so i coded up a solver but it was very inefficient as i just used FDM for a simplified rectangular goemetry. Now my professor asked me to either find an already existing FEM solver that can handle more diversity of structures or code it up myself.
Can you point to some python based packages that already do this? Or some guide to how to code up such a solver using more fundamental packages, if this is easy to do?
Thanks for the help!
PS: in the images below are shown sample 3d and 2d structures I am targeting.

(DOI: 10.1109/SISPAD62626.2024.10733221)

(DOI: 10.1109/SISPAD62626.2024.10733057)

Welcome to SciComp.SE Kitsuit. Why do you want to use cylindrical coordinates in your model?

Have you looked at FEniCS?

I second FEniCS. You write your own weak forms, so it can handle expressions of the form $\int ~rdrd\theta dz$ just by defining $(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (r,\theta,z)$ and meshing a rectangular prism domain in $x$.

@nicoguaro, while using carbon nanotubes, we have cylindrical symmetry so we use cylindrical coordinates to reduce one degree of freedom and reduce simulation time

@WolfgangBangerth , thanks I am just looking into Fenics, seems like exactly what i need

@whpowell96 i am trying to understand Fenics, didnt understand your comment yet, will come back later with more understanding, thanks

FEniCS has a pretty active Discourse forum and axisymmetric problems are a relatively common application. I'm sure that between the tutorials and the forum you can find a good starting point.

@Kutsit, axisymmetric problems are written in the $rz$ plane. This is usually written in Cartesian coordinates.

If you want to avoid differences between Neumann and Dirichlet Boundary conditions you can use Fourier Robin boundary conditions everywhere ($-\vec{n} \cdot \vec{D}=\alpha (V_0-V)+\gamma$). With $\alpha=0$ and $\gamma$ you have Neumann boundary conditions and with $\gamma = 0$ and $\lim\alpha \rightarrow \infty (\text{large})$ you obtain the Dirichlet condition $V=V_0$.
